# Making <ToggleButton> change drawables for other buttons?

Tags: android, toggle, drawable, togglebutton, toggleclass

I'm having this `<ToggleButton>` which i want to change the

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/greenballholep"/> 
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/greenballhole"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/greenballhole"/>
</selector>
```

Of my other buttons, upon turning it on/off.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the name of your XML file containing the quoted text is `button_layout.xml`. This is referenced in `R.drawable.button_layout`. So, programmatically, if you wanted to change a Button's background you would follow:

```
private Button button;
private Button toggle;

…
toggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    protected void onClick() {
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_layout));
    }
}
```

I hope that helps!!

Comment: I'm gonna try it now. However, i'm wondering exactly how to make it work for me.

As for me it seems, like this only works one way around, eg. when i press the toggle button, to toggle it to "off", it makes all the other buttons' drawables become red.png

and then when i toggle it back to "on" the drawables remain red, although i might want them to be toggled back the default?